# Imperturbato o imperturbabile

Tags: adjectives

È corretto dire di una persona:

```
John è imperturbabile.
```

e

```
John è imperturbato.
```

sono corrette entrambe le forme?

Answer (score 4):

Benché simili, per la mia esperienza *imperturbabile* è un aggettivo e dovrebbe essere utilizzato per descrivere una qualità permanente di John.
*Imperturbato* è un participio e mi sembra più adatto ad indicare una condizione temporanea per esempio legata ad uno specifico evento.

Comment: Seguendo il vocabolario Treccani (http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/imperturbato/) anche "imperturbato" è aggettivo, ma meno comune di "imperturbabile". Potrebbe essere interessante riflettere sul maggiore uso di quest'ultimo rispetto all'altro.

Comment: Hai ragione; ma io non credo si possa parlare di maggiore uso di una forma rispetto all'altra; come ho detto nella mia esperienza, il suffisso _"-bile"_ indica una caratteristica intrinseca o permanente della persona/cosa, mentre l'altra forma indicherebbe uno stato contingente o legato ad uno specifico evento.
Atri esempi:
_impressionabile/impressionato_ ; _gonfiabile/gonfiato_ ; _invincibile/invitto_

Comment: @Benedetta:  Anche il [De Mauro](http://dizionario.internazionale.it/avvertenze/6) riporta "[imperturbato](http://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/imperturbato)" come sinonimo di "imperturbabile" con la marca d'uso "di basso uso", mentre invece "[imperturbabile](http://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/imperturbabile)" appare come "comune".

Comment: Ho pensato di aggiungere una mia risposta, perché non mi sembrava che il caso fosse da liquidare in modo così semplice.

Answer (score 2):

La tua domanda è interessante; a prima vista imperturbabile e imperturbato fanno parte della numerosa serie di coppie di aggettivi derivanti da verbi transitivi, come:

- affondare - inaffondabile - inaffondato
- distruggere - indistruttibile - indistrutto
- arrestare - inarrestabile - inarrestato

eccetera.

Nella lista precedente il primo aggettivo indica una caratteristica permanente che consiste nell'essere immune dall'azione del verbo, mentre il secondo aggettivo è la negazione del participio passato, e indica uno stato temporaneo.

Il caso di imperturbabile e imperturbato è però diverso nella pratica, perché l'aggettivo *imperturbabile* viene spesso usato, con riferimento allo stato emotivo o psicologico di una persona, e per lo più con il verbo rimanere, con lo stesso significato di *imperturbato*.

Faccio degli esempi:

```
John è rimasto imperturbabile per due ore davanti all'accusa, 
poi ha ceduto e ha confessato.
```

oppure

```
Non capisco John: a volte rimane imperturbabile davanti alle mie
critiche, altre volte reagisce in modo esagerato
```

In entrambi i casi *imperturbabile* non rappresenta uno stato permanente, ma è un sinonimo di *imperturbato*.

Immagino che questo dipenda dal fatto che quando si parla della psicologia delle persone nulla è immutabile, ed è pertanto facile considerare ogni espressione come legata ad una condizione specifica, per cui in pratica *imperturbabile* viene oggi usato come sinonimo più comune di *imperturbato*.

Di fatto però è possibile usare *imperturbabile* nel senso di impossibile da perturbare. In questo senso *imperturbato* non è un sinonimo di *imperturbabile*.